# Can we define @valid/@validated at method level or at object creation level

Tags: spring-boot

I know that we can use @valid & @validated annotation at rest end points, but can we use them at method or object creation level?

My requirement is, I receive csv text data on calling endpoint, I convert it into object, and now I would like to validate the fields of that object. how it can be done or can I validate the csv text itself in request body, if cst text is as given below.

For eg,

444-44444-4444-4444-44444444;1234;AB;N;0;0;

this is what I receive and each comma separated value is a separate field,
Can I validate this csv or

M converting text into an object which has all these fields,

for eg,

requestObject{

field1 :- 444-44444-4444-4444-44444444  ;

field2 :-1234;

field3 :-ABC     ;

field4 :-N;

field5 :- 0;

field6 :-0;

}

and I want to validate these fields,

Answer (score 0):

you can create your POJO for that:

```
public class MyPojo{
  @NotNull
  private String field1;
  @Size(min=10)
  private String field2;
  ...
}
```

and then create service which method will accept or return that pojo and anotate it with `@Validated`

```
@Validated
public interface MyService{

 @Validated MyPojo getMyPojo(String... params);

 void processMyPojo(@Validated MyPojo mypojo);
}
```

I guess with this structure it should work.

Comment: This did not work for me, but with creating custom Validator worked which I wanted to avoid for such a small functionality

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Validated
public interface MyService{

 @Valid MyPojo getMyPojo(String... params);

 void processMyPojo(@Valid MyPojo mypojo);
}
```